# As template type argument, why doesn't type[N] match its specialized version ---- template<class T> class S<T[]>

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, specialization

Here is a demo (shortened from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_array)):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
template<class T>
struct is_array : std::false_type {};

template<class T>
struct is_array<T[]> : std::true_type {};


class A {};

int main() 
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha;
    std::cout << is_array<A>::value << '\n';
    std::cout << is_array<A[]>::value << '\n';
    std::cout << is_array<A[3]>::value << '\n';
}
```

output([**`live demo`**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ge5vlqGFdxrZtw1V)):

```
false
true
false
```

We can see that `is_array<A[3]>` is resolved as the primary specialization: `template<class T> struct is_array`, and not `template<class T> struct is_array<T[]>`.

It confuses me a fair bit. Of course I know the complete implementation of `std::is_array` (as documented in cppreference) also contains a specialization for length: `template<class T, std::size_t N> struct is_array<T[N]>`, and `std::is_array<A[3]>` will resolve to this specialization as expected. But that cannot explain the uppermost demo, right?

After searching, I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12261762/partial-template-specialization-for-arrays), but it is a question about *how*, not *why*. But in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12261762/partial-template-specialization-for-arrays#comment16439522_12261762), [*@Steve Jessop*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13005/steve-jessop) mentioned:

> I'm not entirely sure, but I think what you've written there is a specialization for arrays of unknown size. That's an incomplete type, but can be used in an extern declaration of an array that some other TU will provide.

---

It seems to related to [it being an **incomplete type**](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.types#6):

> The declared type of an array object might be an array of unknown bound and therefore be incomplete at one point in a translation unit and complete later on; the array types at those two points (“array of unknown bound of T” and “array of N T”) are different types. The type of a pointer to array of unknown bound, or of a type defined by a typedef declaration to be an array of unknown bound, cannot be completed

```
extern int arr[];               // the type of arr is incomplete
int  arr[10];                   // now the type of arr is complete
```

[[basic.types]/6](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.types#6) doesn't offer any other useful information about this.

---

I noticed an error in the sample from the spec, which got me thinking that maybe it is not about specialization, but because `A[3]` cannot match `struct is_array<T[]>`. That's what the compiler seems to affirm:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template<class T>
struct is_array<T[]> : std::true_type {};


class A {};

int main() 
{
    is_array<A[3]> *a; // error
    is_array<A[3]> b; // error
}
```

[**`demo`**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/dPOi20eGIsulM0p6)

---

Above is what I tried to solve this by myself, without success. So I am here to find a **thorough** answer.

Comment: You could add `template<class T, size_t N> struct is_array<T[N]> : std::true_type {};` do handle that situation.

Comment: @Eljay Yes, I know, as I have mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is in the paragraph you quoted yourself:

> The declared type of an array object might be an array of unknown
>   bound and therefore be incomplete at one point in a translation unit
>   and complete later on; **the array types at those two points (“array of
>   unknown bound of T” and “array of N T”) are different types**. The type
>   of a pointer to array of unknown bound, or of a type defined by a
>   typedef declaration to be an array of unknown bound, cannot be
>   completed

Those are different types. While you may "fix" the type of an array *object* after the first point of declaration, it still doesn't change the fact those are different types. They behave differently. For instance:

```
using AI = int[];
using AC = int[3];

AI a1 = {1, 2, 3, 4};
AC a2 = {1, 2, 3, 4}; // error
```

The object `a1` can be initialized with the initializer `{1, 2, 3, 4}`. We see that the type I aliased as `AI` kinda behaves like `auto`, an initializer can be used  to help deduce the complete type.

On the other hand, `a2` causes an error, because I provided too many initializers. And if I were to provide too few, I'd still have 3 elements in my array, where the ones not explicitly initialized will be default initialized.

I hope you are convinced by now those are indeed very different types. So as template arguments, they *shouldn't* match.

Comment: once initialized `a1` and `a2` [seem to be of same type](https://ideone.com/3LHnrq). raw arrays are just too weird for me

Comment: @user463035818 - The *objects* are of the same type (assuming we pass 3 initializers for `a1`). The types are still fundamentally different. They have to be, if we treat `T[]` like an actual type and not just a kludge that allows the bound to be deduced.

Comment: yes I think I got it. Of course `a1`s type cannot be incomplete, so it has to be deduced and once deduced it is the same as `AC`

Comment: ...still raw arrays are too weird for me :P