# Specialising Rcpp::as() for std::array

Tags: r, c++11, rcpp

One of my projects uses C++11 `std::array` for fixed-sized array types, and so I'm trying to specialise `Rcpp::as()` for convenient conversion from `SEXP` to these types. Since this requires partial specialisation, I've followed the `Exporter` route as outlined in Rcpp-extending:

```cpp
#include <RcppCommon.h>
#include <array>

namespace Rcpp {
namespace traits {

// Partial specialisation to allow as<array<T,D>>(...)
template <typename ElementType, int Dimensionality>
class Exporter<std::array<ElementType,Dimensionality>>
{
private:
    std::array<ElementType,Dimensionality> value;

public:
    Exporter (SEXP x)
    {
        std::vector<ElementType> vec = as<std::vector<ElementType>>(x);
        if (vec.size() != Dimensionality)
            throw Rcpp::exception("Array does not have the expected number of elements");
        for (int i=0; i<Dimensionality; i++)
            value[i] = vec[i];
    }
    
    std::array<ElementType,Dimensionality> get () { return value; }
};

} // traits namespace
} // Rcppnamespace

#include <Rcpp.h>
```

Other code within the package can then do, for example,

```cpp
std::array<double,3> arr = Rcpp::as<std::array<double,3>>(vec);
```

I've bundled this up into a [minimal package](https://github.com/jonclayden/Rcpp.asArray) for example purposes; the "real" application is [here](https://github.com/tractor/tractor/blob/master/tractor.track/src/Image.h).

The problem is that this approach compiles and works fine for me locally (macOS, clang), but gcc doesn't like it. The output from a GitHub CI action on the minimal package is below.

```
* installing *source* package ‘Rcpp.asArray’ ...
** using staged installation
** libs
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/opt/R/4.2.2/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/home/runner/work/_temp/Library/Rcpp/include' -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -g -O2  -c main.cpp -o main.o
In file included from /home/runner/work/_temp/Library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/as.h:25,
                 from /home/runner/work/_temp/Library/Rcpp/include/RcppCommon.h:169,
                 from array.h:4,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/home/runner/work/_temp/Library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/internal/Exporter.h: In instantiation of ‘Rcpp::traits::Exporter<T>::Exporter(SEXP) [with T = std::array<double, 3>; SEXP = SEXPREC*]’:
/home/runner/work/_temp/Library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/as.h:87:41:   required from ‘T Rcpp::internal::as(SEXP, Rcpp::traits::r_type_generic_tag) [with T = std::array<double, 3>; SEXP = SEXPREC*]’
/home/runner/work/_temp/Library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/as.h:152:31:   required from ‘T Rcpp::as(SEXP) [with T = std::array<double, 3>; SEXP = SEXPREC*]’
main.cpp:8:62:   required from here
/home/runner/work/_temp/Library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/internal/Exporter.h:31:42: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::array<double, 3>::array(SEXPREC*&)’
   31 |                     Exporter( SEXP x ) : t(x){}
      |                                          ^~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/11/tuple:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11/bits/hashtable_policy.h:34,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11/bits/hashtable.h:35,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11/unordered_map:46,
                 from /home/runner/work/_temp/Library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/platform/compiler.h:153,
                 from /home/runner/work/_temp/Library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/r/headers.h:62,
                 from /home/runner/work/_temp/Library/Rcpp/include/RcppCommon.h:30,
                 from array.h:4,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/11/array:95:12: note: candidate: ‘std::array<double, 3>::array()’
   95 |     struct array
      |            ^~~~~
/usr/include/c++/11/array:95:12: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
/usr/include/c++/11/array:95:12: note: candidate: ‘constexpr std::array<double, 3>::array(const std::array<double, 3>&)’
/usr/include/c++/11/array:95:12: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘SEXP’ {aka ‘SEXPREC*’} to ‘const std::array<double, 3>&’
/usr/include/c++/11/array:95:12: note: candidate: ‘constexpr std::array<double, 3>::array(std::array<double, 3>&&)’
/usr/include/c++/11/array:95:12: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘SEXP’ {aka ‘SEXPREC*’} to ‘std::array<double, 3>&&’
make: *** [/opt/R/4.2.2/lib/R/etc/Makeconf:178: main.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘Rcpp.asArray’
* removing ‘/home/runner/work/Rcpp.asArray/Rcpp.asArray/Rcpp.asArray.Rcheck/Rcpp.asArray’
```

I don't know the internals of `Rcpp` well enough to be sure, but it looks like the default implementation of `Exporter` is being used in preference to the custom one, and failing because there is no `std::array` constructor for `SEXP`, which would involve intrusive modification.

Can anyone suggest a way to resolve this, please?

Comment: "Narps" as a colleague of mine says.  I can only point to the [standard vignette we wrote](https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-extending.pdf) (and which I am sure you read to). It's been quite a while since I last worked this for package of mine but I can take a look.  Otherwise ... GitHub code search may give you hints (search in the github.com/cran org that is a mirror) as the 'pattern' is used in a few places.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried a few things based on other packages, and the only thing I've tried that works is to [specialise only for arrays of a certain length](https://github.com/jonclayden/Rcpp.asArray/blob/51226b5c1e95ce647a9acf0621a03dd13b6b6c7f/src/array.h). I haven't seen anything indicating that the partial specialisation I originally tried isn't allowed, and [similar things seem to work with C-style arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12261808/3921960), but I may have missed something...

Comment: I'll try to find time to kick the tires. We want more of this, possibly also in Rcpp proper, and we may want to support `std::span` too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As best as I can tell your approach was missing a few pieces. The best guide is still the [trusted example by @coatless in the Rcpp Gallery](https://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/custom-templated-wrap-and-as-for-seamingless-interfaces/)

Following that I reduces your header (with a bit of renaming -- sorry, personal style crept in) to (skipping the declaration in step 1) to

```
namespace Rcpp {
  namespace traits {

    template <typename T, std::size_t D> class Exporter<std::array<T,D>> {
      typedef typename std::array<T,D> ATD;

      // Convert the type to a valid rtype.
      const static int RTYPE = Rcpp::traits::r_sexptype_traits<T>::rtype;
      Rcpp::Vector<RTYPE> vec;

    public:
      Exporter(SEXP x): vec(x) {
        if (TYPEOF(x) != RTYPE) Rcpp::stop("Wrong R type for array");
      }
      ATD get() {
        ATD x;
        if (vec.size() != D) Rcpp::stop("Array does not have the exp nb of elements");
        std::memcpy(x.begin(), vec.begin(), D*sizeof(T));
        return x;
      }
    };
  }
}
```

I changed / simplified your usage example to using Rcpp Attribute because, hey, its 2022 and we had them for close a decade so `.Call()` is no longer *de rigeur*:

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
void foo() {
  Rcpp::NumericVector v = Rcpp::NumericVector::create(1,2,3);
  Rcpp::print(v);
  std::array<double,3> a = Rcpp::as<std::array<double,3>>(v);
  Rcpp::Rcout << "Hi "
              << a[0] << " "
              << a[1] << " "
              << a[2] << std::endl;
}
```

And that then works as expected (here from the shell with `littler` loading your package:

```
edd@rob:~/git/rcppasarray(main)$ r -lRcpp.asArray -e'Rcpp.asArray:::foo()'
[1] 1 2 3
Hi 1 2 3
edd@rob:~/git/rcppasarray(main)$
```

It may need an explicit resizing step -- I haven't worked too much with `std::array` to be sure.  I'll clean up a bit more and send you a PR.

Comment: [PR here](https://github.com/jonclayden/Rcpp.asArray/pull/1), for future reference